# Image Overlays with Responsive Grids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running into a problem while trying to use image overlays within a responsive bootstrap grid. Everything looks good when the page is fullscreened, however whenever it goes below 980 width the image bleeds out the bottom of the grid, but then begins to look better and better the smaller the page gets. I know I can use media queries for this, but is there a solution that I'm overlooking?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="content-section">
                 <h1>Placeholder</h1>

                <p>Placeholder</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="content-section">
                 <h1>Placeholder</h1>

                <p>Placeholder</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-section">
                     <h1>Placeholder</h1>

                    <p>Placeholder</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-section">
                     <h1>Placeholder</h1>

                    <div class="image-overlay">
                        <img class="bottom img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/932x468">
                    </div>
                    <p>PlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholderPlaceholderlaceholder</p>
                                                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-section {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom 20px;
}
.image-overlay {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 320px;
}
#image-overlay img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
#image-overlay img.top:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1f8cbm2y/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is giving you problems in tablet resolution I think. So without media queries, you can use `col-sm-*` for tablets.

Here is the jsfiddle [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/1f8cbm2y/1/).